# Display assumptions of a variable

Tags: assumptions, variable-definitions

If I restrict a variable `x` to `x>0` via `$Assumptions=x>0`, is there a way I can get Mathematica to tell me that `x>0`? I would have guessed typing `Attributes[x]` would say something, but it gives `{}`.

Answer (score 5):

I don't yet have the reputation for commenting, but perhaps this suffices as an answer as well: why not just evaluate `$Assumptions` to get a list of active global assumptions about variables?

```
$Assumtions=x>0
$Assumptions
(*x>0*)
```

Comment: (+1) in case `#Assumptions` is a long list involving other variables, you can filter using `Cases[_[___, x, ___]]@$Assumptions` or `Select[Not@*FreeQ[x]]@$Assumptions`